# ionic-native/calendar

Tags: angular, ionic, cordova

Estoy trabajando con cordova-plugin-calendar, hice un ejemplo simple para abrir un calendario con la fecha actual, aquí esta el código donde implemente cada parte

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { Calendar } from '@ionic-native/calendar';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Calendar,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**tab1.page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from '@ionic-native/calendar';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab2Page {

  constructor(private calendar: Calendar) {

  }

 openCalendar() {
    this.calendar.openCalendar(new Date()).then(
        (msg) => { console.log(msg); },
        (err) => { console.log(err); }
    );
  }
}
```

**tab1.page.html**

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab 2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Tab 2</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <button ion-button (click)="openCalendar()">Open Calendar on Current Date</button>

</ion-content>
```

El problema con esto es que cuando corro la aplicacion en el emulador de android, la pantalla me aparece en blanco, no se si me falta algo mas de incluir o si estoy colocando el codigo de forma incorrecta?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda

Comment: Teclea **adb devices** y dime que te muestra

Comment: Muestra esto:

List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

Comment: en chrome dijita esto **chrome://inspect** y debe mostrarte tu app corriendo en localhost, dale inspeccionar y dime que error te muestra.